# mongojs [Error: connection closed ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongojs

I'm using mognojs version 0.7.2 and socket.io, and works fine but when I don`t make queries to datatabase for a while, maybe a timeout close the connection, and after when i try to make any query again the callback response is [Error: connection closed ]

I`m added to add auto_reconnect but I get the same error

```
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections, {auto_reconnect:true});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check the MongoDB logs?

Comment: I'm using mongohq sandbox (free plan). and I don't have access to that feature :(

Comment: Do they have a support forum or something similar? I sounds like an infrastructure issue, and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

In version 0.7.7 on mongojs, there is no forward of connection (server) option to the native mongodb driver layer.
Your auto_reconnect is, in my sense, useless here. I'm looking for a workaround for this issue